# Error with server install of new MVC app and MVC Release Candidate 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation

I have developed a small application using MVC RC2.

The application works fine in my development environment, but fails when I push it to my production environment with the following error:

```
Method not found: 
'Void System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute
(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection, System.String)'.
```

App pool is running .NET 2.x
Recent install of .NET Framework 3.5 SP1
Recent install of MVC RC2

Has anyone run into this problem?  It seems to be missing the necessary method in the set of assemblies available to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are not referring to the same assemblies on both machines.

Check the web.config differences between system.web which is used by iis6 and localhost cassini and system.webServer which is used by IIS7.

Also try dropping MVC dlls in the bin directory of the site to see if it is not getting them from the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever have ASP.NET MVC V1 installed?  I did and had a similar experience.  I then downloaded the documentation located [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d34f9eaa-fcbe-4e20-b2fd-a9a03de7d6dd&displaylang=en) and checked out the section "Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Project to ASP.NET MVC 2"

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IIS you are using ?
In IIS 6.0 you have to add MVC in Application Extension mapping.

Please check this blog post.
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx